# Ionic 4 - Can’t write on a ion-searchbar when a modal is opened

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I’m experiencing problems with my Windows 10 app on Ionic 4 + Angular. Whenever I open a modal, I can’t click on my ion-searchbar (which is on the header of the parent window). I have removed the modal backdrop already and I can click other buttons, but I can’t write on the searchbar, even calling the function "setFocus()".

Searchbar code:

HTML

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar class="searchbar" [(ngModel)]="search" inputmode="text" placeholder="Search..." (click)="searchBarFocus()">
  </ion-searchbar>
```

TS

```
searchBarFocus() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.searchbar.setFocus();
  }, 100);
}
```

Any idea? On a browser it works great, but not on Windows (built with Cordova).

Comment: is your search bar in the modal?

Comment: I assume you didn't use ion-modal for that, did you you use angular bootstrap ? maybe you need to give ion-searchbar higher z-index value ?

Comment: It is outside the modal. 
I did use ion-modal. Other elements such buttons can be clicked, so I didn't even think about using z-index. I will give it a try!

Comment: I have tried with z-index but I got the same result :(